# jq: parse json array 0

Tags: json, sh, jq

I need to get USD_in

My jq code:

```
jq '.USD_in[0]'
```

JSON SOURCE:

```
[
  {
    "USD_in": "2.0200",
    "USD_out": "2.0420",
    "EUR_in": "2.2400",
    "EUR_out": "2.2970",
    "RUB_in": "3.0500",
    "RUB_out": "3.2300",
    "GBP_in": "0.0000",
    "GBP_out": "0.0000",
    "CAD_in": "0.0000",
    "CAD_out": "0.0000",
    "PLN_in": "4.2000",
    "PLN_out": "5.4500",
    "UAH_in": "7.3000",
    "UAH_out": "9.4500",
    "SEK_in": "0.0000",
    "SEK_out": "0.0000",
    "CHF_in": "0.0000",
    "CHF_out": "0.0000",
    "USD_EUR_in": "0.8795",
    "USD_EUR_out": "1.0970",
    "USD_RUB_in": "62.5390",
    "USD_RUB_out": "0.0149",
    "RUB_EUR_in": "0.0133",
    "RUB_EUR_out": "69.3500",
    "JPY_in": "0.0000",
    "JPY_out": "0.0000",
    "CNY_in": "0.0000",
    "CNY_out": "0.0000",
    "CZK_in": "0.0000",
    "CZK_out": "0.0000",
    "NOK_in": "0.0000",
    "NOK_out": "0.0000",
    "filial_id": "16",
    "sap_id": "50011756",
    "info_worktime": "Пн 9 00 19 00    |Вт 9 00 19 00    |Ср 9 00 19 00    |Чт 9 00 19 00    |Пт 9 00 19 00    |Сб 9 00 15 00    |Вс        |",
    "street_type": "пр.",
    "street": "Партизанский",
    "filials_text": "Отделение 100/212",
    "home_number": "8-49",
    "name": "Брест",
    "name_type": "г."
  }
]
```

jq: error (at :0): Cannot index array with string "USD_in"

Comment: Not sure what you are after Friend but USD_in[0] is treating the value of USD_in as array when it's a string.

Comment: Are you using `jq` or `jQuery`? `jQuery` is a JavaScript library, `jq` is a shell tool.

Comment: i'm use jq tool, sorry, thanks all) and sorry for english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You evidently meant:

```
.[0] | .USD_in
```

which can be abbreviated to `.[0].USD_in`

You might also wish to consider:

```
  .[].USD_in
```